# Is there a faster way to find out if a stored procedure exists before calling it via OLE DB?

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, oledb, ado

The 3d party C++ application that I was asked to support first checks if a stored procedure exists before making a call to any stored procedure:

```
CWSConnectionPtr spConn = DB::CreateConnection(bstrConnID);
_CommandPtr spCmd(__uuidof(Command));
spCmd->PutRefActiveConnection(spConn.GetPtr()); // resets connection
spCmd->PutCommandText(bstrQueryName);
spCmd->PutCommandType(adCmdStoredProc);
spCmd->GetParameters()->Refresh(); // generates SP call for params

if(spCmd->GetParameters()->GetCount() == 0)
{
    LOG_ERROR((_T("Stored procedure not found: %s"), (LPCTSTR)bstrQueryName));
    _THROW_ERROR(E_FAIL, IDS_MSG_SP_NOT_FOUND);
}
```

On the SQL Server back end that translates into the following call per every stored procedure call:

```
exec sp_procedure_params_rowset N'procName',1,N'dbo',NULL
```

The ADO connection object uses `provider=SQLOLEDB` in the connection string.

Is there a faster way to make sure there is a procedure we are about to call, before the application will further invest into populating the parameter values, sometimes with the large BLOBs?

Comment: You could look into querying the information schema views.

Comment: I am aware of that, but what makes you think that would be faster?

Comment: create another stored procedure or function that checks existence of any given stored procedure

Comment: Is that going to be faster?

Comment: I think the issue @ajeh is concerned about is the individual calls to SQL to check the existence in any form. Could you do a single query to cache all the stored procedures in memory (maybe a HashTable type object) and then use this for quick checks? If for whatever reason the sproc is not found you could refresh the cache object to ensure no schema changes had occurred and if it still doesn't exist after refresh you could consider it non-existent?

Comment: Well a really fast thing to do would be to NOT check if the stored procedure exists, and just trap (ie catch) and handle the error if it doesn't.

Comment: are you sure you're only trying to see if the proc exists, and not trying to get the proc parameters?  if you have to get the parameters regardless i'm not sure why you would change anything

Comment: The later code would populate the pre-defined set of parameters for each procedure being called anyway, so whatever the `Refresh()` is bringing back is ignored. So the answer is proabaly Yes.